# What's with the abundance of black balloons in NF's videos?

Tags: music-video

Recently, I have been listening to a lot more NF, and sometimes watching the music videos that go with them. I've noticed that in some of his videos, including The Search, Real, Why, and various others, he is pictured holding, or near a bunch of black balloons. Why have these balloons been put into many NF videos, do they stand for something? Do they represent something from his childhood?

Answer (score 2):

While there isn't any official information on this, in many of NF's recent videos there is a trend of these black balloons being present.

As evident by the tone and lyrics used, the contrast between the black clothing and items against the lighter colors used by the other individuals (see: [The Search](https://youtu.be/fnlJw9H0xAM)) can be used to describe mood, state of mind and health.

[Adam McDonald](https://justrandomthings.com/2019/06/10/nf-the-search-lyrics-review-and-song-meaning/) (2019) suggests:

> The black balloons resemble his burdens, that follow him around attached to his cart.

Further reading/analysis on the topic:

- Adam McDonald's [NF – The Search (Lyrics Review and Song Meaning)](https://justrandomthings.com/2019/06/10/nf-the-search-lyrics-review-and-song-meaning/)
- Clifford Stumme's [What does "The Search" by NF mean?](https://www.popsongprofessor.com/blog/2019/5/31/what-does-the-search-by-nf-mean)

Comment: Additionnaly, black balloons are the symbol of overdose awareness, which is how he lost his mum.
The symbolisms in his music videos are so rich...

Answer (score 0):

They represent his burdens as he says in "The Search", something along the lines of "I brought a few burdens with me", and he points to the balloons.

Answer (score 0):

It represents that he has not quite got over his imperfections and I respect that and the balloons represent all his dark thoughts and feelings

Answer (score 0):

They mean his burdens. He carries them around and talks to them in the lyrics in the song "Leave me alone". I totally understand his personalization there.